# Rails: How to get a Jquery function to act on a newly added partial?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, partial, renderpartial

I'm working on an ajax star rating system.
For the stars I've used the label's of radio buttons.
When the page loads if the item has a rating (i.e. 3) it will check radio button 3 and all labels before it will be colored (Mouseover also changes the image).
This code is run when $(document).ready and lives in /public/javascript/rating_ballot_index.js

My problem is that because the rating is on the index page (so multiple forms) after the form is submitted (by clicking the label) I need to reload the form. I do this from the 'create.js.erb' file (After an item is clicked a class 'clicky' is added to know which form to remove).

```
('.clicky').closest("tr").replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => @product, :locals => {:product_class => "clear_rating"}) %>");
```

After the new partial is inserted the code from rating_ballot_index.js does not respond to this newly added partial (since the document has already been loaded).
If i try running the function again, the next time I submit a rating, it submits it twice.
Is there a way I can stop the function from running the first time, then rerun it or make the original function recognize the newly added partial?

I Hope what I wrote makes sense!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: The problem was that when calling the .replaceWith it was replacing it with an identical partial, so jQuery didn't realise it was a new element. I ended up replacing it with .empty() and then .append()

Answer (score 0):

Because writing your js function this way you only rely on the dom as it was on load.

To let it be aware of changes, you should use `live` or better: `delegate`.

[Here is a short article explaining the differences.](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had already read that article and tried using bind, live, delegate. Everything! But nothing worked.
I eventually found what the problem was. When calling the .replaceWith it was replacing it with an identical partial, so jquery didn't realise it was a new element. I ended up replacing it with .empyt() and then .append()